# IIS6 301 redirect while preserving paths

Tags: redirect, iis-6, http-status-code-301

I'm having a problem with an IIS6 301 redirect.

I've set up the following redirect for the domain `domain.com` to go to `www.domain.com$S$Q` under the Home Directory tab in Site Properties.

If I navigate to `domain.com` I get redirected to `www.domain.com` with no problems. But if I go to `domain.com/dir` I get redirected to `www.domain.com/dir/dir`.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You want to follow [these instructions](http://www.highposition.net/301-redirect-tutorial-iis/) to set up an HTTP 301.

**Edit:** For what its worth it sounds like you need to check "The client will be sent to a permanent redirection for this resource" on the Home Directory tab.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I'd followed those instructions. I have the permanent redirect box checked. It seemed to want the 'Exact url' box to be checked also. I had it set up before and don't remember needing to check that box. Not sure why I have to now.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the " The exact URL entered above" checkbox seemed to fix the problem.